# from table it read only int value from EmpID but when it string its show error

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

This is the webmethod with ajax and jquery. when the EmpID is like 123,12,123456 it open the popup box and show the output as i want but when EmpID is like A001,ABC it show the error like "Error while retrieving data of :" how to solve...
Thanks in Advance
Query Data:-

```
 $(document).on("click", ".editButton", function () {
                $("#myModal").focus();
                var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
                console.log(id);
                $("#btnUpdate").attr("edit-id", id);
                //alert(id);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Post",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Default3.aspx/EditData",
                    data: '{eid: ' + id + '}',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var empDetails = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                        $.each(empDetails, function (index, value) {
                            $("#FirstName1").val(value.EmpID);
                            $("#MiddleName1").val(value.EmpName);
                            $("#Surname1").val(value.EmpAddress);
                            //alert("hi");
                        });

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error while retrieving data of :" + id);
                    }
                });

            });
        });
```

Html Table:-

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">

        <br />

        <br />
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Admin Employee Details Tables
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                        <div id="dataTables-example_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap no-footer">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="dataTables_length" id="dataTables-example_length">
                                        <label>
                                            Show
                                        <select name="dataTables-example_length" aria-controls="dataTables-example" class="form-control input-sm" id="select">
                                            <option value="5">5</option>
                                            <option value="10">10</option>
                                            <option value="25">25</option>
                                            <option value="50">50</option>
                                            <option value="100">100</option>
                                        </select>
                                            entries</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div id="dataTables-example_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
                                        <label>Search:<input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="dataTables-example" id="searchtxt" /></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="dataTables-example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer " role="grid" aria-describedby="dataTables-example_info">
                                        <thead>  
                                            <tr role="row">  
                                                <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTables-example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 175px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Rendering engine: activate to sort column descending">Emp ID</th>  
                                                <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTables-example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 203px;" aria-label="Browser: activate to sort column ascending">Emp Name</th>  
                                                <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTables-example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 184px;" aria-label="Platform(s): activate to sort column ascending">Emp Address</th>  
                                                </tr>  
                                        </thead>
                                                <tbody>  
                                                    <% for (var data = 0; data < TableData.Rows.Count; data++)    
                                                                                                   { %>  
                                                        <tr class="gradeA odd " role="row">  
                                                            <td class="sorting_1">  
                                                                <%=TableData.Rows[data]["EmpID"]%>  
                                                            </td>  
                                                            <td>  
                                                                <%=TableData.Rows[data]["EmpName"]%>  
                                                            </td>  
                                                            <td>  
                                                                <%=TableData.Rows[data]["EmpAddress"]%>  
                                                            </td>  

                                                            <td>  
                                                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary editButton" data-id="<%=TableData.Rows[data]["EmpID"] %>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" name="submitButton" id="btnEdit" value="Edit" />
                                                            </td>  
                                                            <td>  
                                                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary deleteButton" data-id="<%=TableData.Rows[data]["EmpId"] %>" name="submitButton" id="btnDelete" value="Delete" />  
                                                            </td>  
                                                        </tr>  
                                                        <% } %>  
                                                </tbody>  
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.table-responsive -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

C# Code-

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string EditData(string eid)
     {
         string jsondata;
         using(var con=new SqlConnection(ConnectString))
         {
             var query = "Select * from NewEmp where EmpID='" + eid + "' ";
             using(var cmd=new SqlCommand(query, con))
             {
                 using(var sda=new SqlDataAdapter())
                 {
                     cmd.Connection = con;
                     sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                     TableData.Clear();
                     sda.Fill(TableData);
                     jsondata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TableData);

                 }
             }
         }
         return jsondata;
     }
```

Comment: you are not showing where is the actual error happens,  if you debug the code, and check if there there is server side error, then we could help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the ID field is set as an integer value somewhere, such that numbers will work but letters will throw an error. Your JSON looks messed up, too, with weird field mapping:

```
$("#FirstName1").val(value.EmpID);
                        $("#MiddleName1").val(value.EmpName);
                        $("#Surname1").val(value.EmpAddress);
```

FirstName may not map to EmpID well. Middlename to EmpName, etc.

But overall, it sounds like something is expecting an integer input and you're giving it letters. Look for that and either change the input expectation to varchar/string or change the input to only consist of numbers.